# What is the common term to express the barrier of a balcony?

Tags: word-request

The barrier of a balcony could by built in many forms like these

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

or

[image]

Should we call it "**balcony railings**" or "**balcony fence**"?

Comment: Try take a look here: https://www.avcon.com/when-is-fence-a-railing-and-railing-a-fence/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Railing* tends to refer to the fence-style barrier, made of metal or wood, and with nothing filling the gaps between posts. Technically the "rail" is the top surface, the horizontal piece at the top, but collectively the posts that support it is the *railing*. The top rail may be called a "handrail" if it is meant to be held, or a "guardrail" if it is there for safety.

A *balustrade* is like a railing, but the handrail is supported by fixed posts or pillars. The pillars may be made of different material to the rail and perhaps be part of the stone balcony.

The final photo example of a stone wall on top of a structure would be either a *parapet*, or just a *wall* (possibly *guard wall*). In old castles, the guard wall may also be referred to as the *ramparts*, but that may also include the rest of the structure too, not just the wall.

Anything else is really a *barrier*.

Comment: Just to add a note on frequency/formality: *wall* and *railing(s)* are probably the most common in colloquial use, and *parapet* is not uncommon, though slightly more associated with grand or historical buildings (e.g. church towers, castles).  *Balustrade* and *guard wall* are rather more formal and technical; *ramparts* is distinctly historical.

Comment: @PLL Agreed. OP included photos of historical buildings and the historical names would apply.

Comment: Astralbee: Absolutely; my comment wasn’t a criticism of your answer, just some additional information which I think is helpful for someone who hasn’t met these words before.

Comment: For what it’s worth, I associate “parapet” with castles, too, possibly even more than “ramparts.” Also, “crenelation” is yet-another term for those short walls on top of castle roofs or walls, giving defenders cover and so on.

Answer (score 10):

I would call the top one a railing. The next two are railings with glass panels or glass-paneled railings. The last I would call a wall or [parapet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parapet) (this Wikipedia link features your photo).

Answer (score 2):

The word parapet (as mentioned in [TypeIA's abswer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/231994/27840))  describes a wall-like structure that surrounds a balcony or roof. Another related term is [Balustrade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baluster) which refers to a series of pillars or poles supporting a handrail. Other related terms are **guard rail** and **ledge**.

Answer (score 0):

The Decemberists - Here I Dreamt I Was An Architect (Lyrics) 
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sy0NySwzDzY)

And I am nothing of a builder
But here I dreamt I was an architect
And I built this balustrade
To keep you home, to keep you safe
From the outside world
But the angles and the corners
Even though my work is unparalleled
They never seemed to meet
This structure fell about our feet
And we were free to go